# r markdown print issue

Tags: r, r-markdown

I run this code:

````
## Table 1
```{r Table 1,echo = FALSE,include = FALSE}
MyVars <- c("age", "male", "OutPatient", "BMI","smoking")
CatVars <- c("male","OutPatient","smoking")
nonnormalvars <- testnonnormal(MyVars,CatVars,ModAS_DB)
tab1tot <- CreateTableOne(vars = MyVars, data = ModAS_DB, factorVars = CatVars)
tab1strat <- CreateTableOne(vars = MyVars, data = ModAS_DB, factorVars = CatVars, strata = "trt1")
tab1tot <- print(tab1tot, nonnormal = nonnormalvars)
tab1strat <- print(tab1strat, nonnormal = nonnormalvars)
Table1 <- cbind(tab1tot,tab1strat)
```

`r print(Table1)`
````

but it dose not print anything.
Also when I print from inside the code I get a very ugly table that does not look like a table at all

Any ideas on any of the issues?

Comment: Just a note: You can use 4 backticks to show 3 backticks inside a code chunk. I edited it, and it's in queue for now.

Comment: Regarding your issue, can you please what you receive as the output? Right now, it is not reproducible.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/s40hm2

Answer (score 0):

Solved both by doing the following

Instead of:
`` `r print(Table1)` ``

use:
`` `r knitr::kable(Table1, format = "markdown")` ``